# Which is the correct version of jetty-servlets.jar for GeoServer 2.6-RC1

Tags: geoserver, installation, jetty

I am trying to determine the correct version of jetty-servlets to install.  I have installed GeoServer 2.6-RC1.

Now I need to install jetty-servlets.jar to enable CORS as mentioned here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html

It directs you to download the jetty-servlet here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/

Which is the correct version to download if I have installed GeoServer 2.6-RC1?

Answer (score 4):

I found an amazing and easy solution to determine the correct version of **jetty-servlets.jar** for GeoServer.

The solution is to open the **jetty directory**

- Windows: C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\jetty\lib
- OS X: /Users//Library/Application Support/GeoServer/jetty/lib

You will find some jar files ends with the jetty version before the extension.

(like: **jetty-client-7.6.13.v20130916.jar**) for **Geoserver 2.8**.

- Remember the version number from the file (**7.6.13.v20130916**) and browes to this [URL](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/) and select the matching version to the version we got from the last step.
- Choose the file (like: jetty-servlets-7.6.13.v20130916.jar ) no other file needed.

Paste the downloaded **jar** into  **jetty directory**

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct version!  It is jetty-servlets-9.2.2.v20140723.jar.

Comment: How did you find it? Is there a methodology to find the jetty version of the geoserver?